# What is this PIND command

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a code that reads the value of a sensor and because it needs to be very fast it does not use digitalRead but a strange form of reading. In the top of the code it shows:

```
#define IRSENSOR PIND
int irpin = 2;
```

I have no idea why this PIND referes to my arduino pin 2, but it only work if my sensor is in pin 2. If I want to change to pin 9 and only change the irpin varialbe it does not work. Why?

To read the sensor I use this code:

```
while (IRSENSOR & (1 << irpin )) {
```

Have no idea why this work. Does anyone know this kind of programming with arduino?

Comment: That's not a strange form of reading, that's the normal form of reading. The Arduino libraries are the strange form of reading.

Comment: Agree, but I am a beginner, sorry. Do you know how to create a variable/const of PIND without using define?

Comment: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PIND refers to the arduino's IO register for input in port D

Without arduino, one has to refer to pins by specific bits in 3 different sets of registers for each port (PIN*, DDR*, and PORT*; B,C, and D).

The arduino code makes it simpler to pick out a single pin by hiding all of this, but it does make reading a pin take much longer.

In the code, the specific pin is being selected by masking off all but the "irpin" bit in PIND, so changing irpin will pick a different bit and thus a different pin.

Pin 9 is actually bit 1 of port B, not D, so see if this works:

```
#define IRSENSOR PINB
int irpin = 1;
```

alternatly, using a reference instead of define,

```
volatile uint8_t& IRSENSOR = PINB;
int irpin = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly! One final question: I would like to change #define pino_sensor_infravermelho_PIN  PIND -->> const byte pino_sensor_infravermelho_PIN = PIND;    BUT it does not work, IDE does not allow me to compile. How to solve this?

Comment: How did you know it's 1? It worked but I would like to know how to discover it!

Comment: I just looked at this cool image I found on google to get the pin numbers, http://www.pighixxx.com/test/portfolio-items/uno/?portfolioID=314 If you are really interested in how all these registers work it is all described in the atmega328 datasheet.

Comment: You can get rid of the #define with a reference to a volatile unsigned 8 bit value. See my edit for the code

Comment: Nice!!!! I am not lazy, I used the image http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168 but your link is much better cause in the link I showed you the pins are not right. tHANK YOU so much really I could not use define and it helped me alot!

Comment: @Samul: I don't see any difference between the two, other than one shows the Arduino and the other shows the IC.

Answer (score 1):

Reason explained by @BrettM. To be more perfect use macros everywhere, e.g.:

```
#define IRSENSOR PIND
#define IRSENSOR_PIN PD2

while (IRSENSOR & _BV(IRSENSOR_PIN)) {
```

Arduino's *digitalWrite(),digitalRead(),pinMode()* functions are useless for more serious coding because they are 1) slow 2) you cannot address pins not connected to headers (e.g. at *Arduino2560*).

Comment: Thank you so much! do you know how to declare those 2 variables without using define?

Comment: It's rather complex task because depends what is intended usage. To be precise you need consider using in inline assembler, proper resolving variables in debugger when watching, IO vs. MEM access (_SFR_MEM vs. _SFR_IO) etc. PIND, PD2 itself is also #define. I would not experiment with it without good reason to make more reusable and readable code (=writing common libs not hardcoded to particular device), e.g. define port+pin as WORD (hi=port, lo=pin) and implementing own macros.

Comment: BTW: You do not need using define at all, if define is problem:

    *while (PIND & _BV(PD2))*

Comment: You are awsome, I will use it inside the while without declaring any variable. Could you please help me understand this: -->> while (porta_pino_sensor_infravermelho & (1 << pino_sensor_infravermelho)) { <<--. I know & is bitwise and and << is bitshift but it does not make any sense to me! Have you ever seen this way of reading a pin HIGH/LOW?

Comment: HIGH=1, LOW=0, it's just strange macroization of trivial things (done even wrong way because HIGH and LOW are really not too unique names in namespace). Almost any port has normally 8 pins, it equals BYTE, particular pin corresponds to bit. Just trivial bitwise opration if bit is high level then do looping.

Comment: so you are saying that if I am using pin 9 then pino_sensor_infravermelho should have 01000000 ? I cant understand this 'while" cause I dont know the value of pino_sensor_infravermelho

Comment: @Samul: I recommend retaining the macro definitions. They don't cause any slowdown during runtime and they make the code easier for others (and eventually yourself) to read and understand.